# UWP community toolkit RoundImageEx image not showing

Tags: xaml, uwp, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml, windows-community-toolkit

I have the following DataTemplate for my GridView

```
        <DataTemplate x:Key="GridViewItemTemplate">
        <Grid Margin="5,10" MaxWidth="80">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <!-- Vendor image-->
            <toolkitControls:RoundImageEx IsCacheEnabled="True" PlaceholderSource="/Assets/Samples/AnotherSampleImage.png" PlaceholderStretch="Uniform" Source="/Assets/Samples/SampleImage.png" Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Padding="0,5,0,0" Text="{Binding NameEn}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="{StaticResource SmallTextSize}"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Here I'm using `RoundImageEx` control from UWP community toolkit. The problem is that neither Image not ImagePlaceholder is not showing.
I've tried using the `ImageEx` control from the toolkit and it works great.

GridView using ImageEx in the DataTemplate (it works just fine)
[image: GridView using ImageEx in the DataTemplate (it works just fine)]

GridView using RoundImageEx in the DateTemplate (images not showing)
[image: GridView using RoundImageEx in the DateTemplate (images not showing)]

Is it some kind of a bug or I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Method 1:

Set `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` as `Stretch` for your `RoundImageEx` control

Code Sample

```
<toolkitControls:RoundImageEx IsCacheEnabled="True" PlaceholderSource="/Assets/Samples/AnotherSampleImage.png" 
                              PlaceholderStretch="Uniform" Source="/Assets/Samples/SampleImage.png" Stretch="Uniform" 
                              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
```

#### Method 2:

Set `Width` and `Height` for your `RoundImageEx` control

Code Sample

```
<toolkitControls:RoundImageEx IsCacheEnabled="True" PlaceholderSource="/Assets/Samples/AnotherSampleImage.png" 
                              PlaceholderStretch="Uniform" Source="/Assets/Samples/SampleImage.png" Stretch="Uniform"
                              Width="100" Height="100"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I ended up using the first method and it works as a charm!